# Getting Rope To 'Swing'

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have bunch of Cylinders connected with Hinge joints, as per a youtube tutorial.  Now the hinge joints move when an ExplosionForce is applied to them, but I want them to 'swing' back and forth when they are moved via the animation.

So I have the top Cylinder's RigiedBody set to Kinematic, and I animate that along the X axis to the right.  Then it stops abruptly, and i want the bottom or the rest of the 'rope' to swing a bit further to the right then back again like a rope would.  Ultimately I want to attach a spotlight to this rope and light up my scene.  But I can't get the rope to swing, it just stays static.

I've exported the scene as a package, you can download it here:
https://www.pastefile.com/Up59SO

Here is an animation of the rope not swinging:
[image]

Please help.  This is really annoying and I cannt see why it shouldnt be working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make sure all rigidbodies are in the root of the scene; not parented to anything. Secondly, you have to use physics forces to get the elements to swing. However, you can't apply forces to kinematic objects. So what I would advise is instead of setting the root of the rope as kinematic to freezing its position on the Y axis.

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody rigidbody;
    [SerializeField] float power = 25;
    [SerializeField] float speed = 5;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.right * Mathf.Cos(Time.time * speed) * power);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that looks exactly like what I was trying to achieve. Could you export that into a package please!? That'd be amazing!!

Comment: I don't really understand where the script goes either, on which object?

Comment: @Chud37 The script is an example that you can attach to the root of the rope. And [here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DaiAZUXPoRnYzRqE_BQRNoXipVQo-duI) the package.

Comment: this is perfect and exactly what I wanted.  Could you explain the equation for me, as I dont get it it? Its only applying a force to the top cylinder, is that right? But what does the maths do, I'm not clever enough to understand that part!?

Comment: Yep, it's only applying the force to the top cylinder. `Mathf.Cos()` is the main function you need to understand, it smoothly goes from -1 to +1 when we pass it a value from 0 to PI (3.142). If we pass it the current time (`Time.time`) it will take ~3.1 seconds to make the full cycle. We can speed it up or slow it down by multiplying the time by `speed`. Then we multiply `Vector3.right` by this value, which is essentially `new Vector3(1,0,0)` this simply ensures we only move on the x-axis. Finally, we multiply the vector by `power` to extend the range of movement and apply it as a force.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this could help, https://answers.unity.com/questions/1244519/how-to-randomly-set-the-direction-of-an-object-and.html?_ga=2.69603664.1732232616.1585344454-527098876.1571345094

Try thinking of it like wind.

Comment: The problem with that is I need the bottom of the rope to swing back as it will be moving back and forward, If I go with a 'wind' solution, the wind will only blow in one direction and move the rope always in that direction.